# Processing one set of numbers at a time

Tags: c#

I am dividing a bigtext file 'file1' using the code below into 64 byte sets. I want this code to process the first 64 bytes and then feed that data to Main() for further processing. Once processing in Main() is done, I would like program to comeback here to process next set of 64 bytes and so on till all the data in 'file1' is processed. How this can be done? Please advise.

```
public static List<byte> ByteValueCaller()
            {
              List<byte> numbers = new List<byte>();
              GetValue(0, numbers);
              return numbers;
            }

        public static void GetValue(int startingByte, List<byte> numbers)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"C:\Users\file1.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
            {
                //determines if the last position to use is inside your stream, or if the last position is the end of the stream.
                int bytesToRead = startingByte + 64 > br.BaseStream.Length ? (int)br.BaseStream.Length - startingByte : 64;


                //move your stream to the given possition
                br.BaseStream.Seek(startingByte, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                //populates databuffer with the given bytes
                byte[] dataBuffer = br.ReadBytes(bytesToRead);

                numbers.AddRange(dataBuffer);

                //recursive call to the same 
                if (startingByte + bytesToRead < fs.Length)
                    GetValue(startingByte + bytesToRead, numbers);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why just don't return `br.ReadBytes(bytesToRead)` result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that a recursive function is a good idea, I would do something like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int chunkSize = 64;

        foreach (IEnumerable<byte> bytes in ReadByChunk(chunkSize))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("==========================================");
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes.ToArray()));
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<byte>> ReadByChunk(int chunkSize)
    {
        IEnumerable<byte> result;
        int startingByte = 0;

        do
        {
            result = ReadBytes(startingByte, chunkSize);
            startingByte += chunkSize;
            yield return result;
        } while (result.Any());
    }

    public static IEnumerable<byte> ReadBytes(int startingByte, int byteToRead)
    {
        byte[] result;

        using (FileStream stream = File.Open(@<path>, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
            int bytesToRead = Math.Max(Math.Min(byteToRead, (int)reader.BaseStream.Length - startingByte), 0);
            reader.BaseStream.Seek(startingByte, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            result = reader.ReadBytes(bytesToRead);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Note that doing this way, the file will open and close everytime you read a  chunk

Comment: @Bidou.....Thanks a lot for your help....How Can I use the output main as input to a method that returns a string?? .................string aiwa = Class.Method(IEnumerable<byte> bytes in ReadByChunk(chunkSize));  Please advise.